# Any idea what this structure in my attic might be?

Tags: attic, joists

I have no idea what this structure in my attic is or what's inside it. It's about 10' x 15' and sits above my dining room. It's made of plywood and drywall and extends to the edge of the roof. There isn't anything significant beneath it from what I can tell, just a small air vent.

The house was built in the 70s and has had its fair share of foundation issues if that offers any kind of clue. I initially thought the ceiling damage was a result of the shifting foundation, but I noticed it's directly beneath this structure, so I assume it bears some significant weight.

Any idea what this could be? Am I risking anything by breaking down some of the drywall to see what's inside?

[image: structure]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @crip659, it isn't about weight. Wood moves with the seasons, and if there's non-standard framing boxing in that area it could certainly explain the problem.

Answer (score 14):

My guess is a former light well.  It looks like we are seeing the BACK of the drywall there, which would corroborate this a little. If you poke a hole and see the drywall has been painted white on the other side (the inside of the shaft formed by this structure) that would be further evidence.  If it's not painted white or if the space is not empty, that would be evidence I'm wrong.

There would have been a skylight mounted in the roof, a white-painted shaft leading to the room below, and in the room, an open hole in the ceiling or perhaps a lens of some kind. A diffuser or a translucent picture of clouds or something.

The skylight may have leaked and a previous owner may have chosen to remove rather than replace it.    The damage to the ceiling and wall may be from the leak, or from settling of the house, or both.

Working against my theory --- if the house was *built* in 1970, the ceiling looks original, there does not appear to be a patch there.  Is there any evidence of a roof repair above this thing?

Comment: Great idea, and my question exactly (though it should be in a comment instead). Also, is there evidence that the "vent" originally had ducting to it? It may have been an HVAC return.

Comment: Or, if in the American Southwest, a swamp cooler?

Comment: @jay613 
Thanks for the input. Here's that section of the roof:
https://imgur.com/T8tNbft

(oh and the skylights on the far side are 100% not a part of the structure)

Comment: Probably reading too much into one photo but that roof looks relatively new.   Closer to 5 or 10 than 50 years old.

Comment: @mr_moany_wiggles please edit that image into your original question. Not everyone will see it down here in a comment on an answer.

Comment: Look at other houses in your neighbourhood that are of the same design and see if any of them have a skylight in the same location.